# How to change permission on external hard drive in Ubuntu

Tags: usb, permissions, mount

I formatted my External USB hard drive(466 GB) and now is not letting me make changes to it, like adding or deleting files.  I can only read files.

I tried different solutions but nothing helped.

```
Sys. de fichiers Type     Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
udev             devtmpfs   1.9G    8.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs            tmpfs      375M    1.4M  374M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        ext4        18G     12G  5.2G  69% /
none             tmpfs      4.0K       0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none             tmpfs      5.0M       0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             tmpfs      1.9G     49M  1.8G   3% /run/shm
none             tmpfs      100M     48K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda6        ext4       268G    244G   10G  97% /home
/dev/sdb1        fuseblk    466G    156M  466G   1% /mnt/usb-WD_Elements_10A8_575842314134334139333135-0:0-part1
```

after using mount command the output is:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
/dev/sda6 on /home type ext4 (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=samsung-toshiba-r)
/dev/sdb1 on /mnt/usb-WD_Elements_10A8_575842314134334139333135-0:0-part1 type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
gvfsd-fuse on /root/.gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev)
```

update  02:
The output now is

[image]

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
/dev/sda6 on /home type ext4 (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=samsung-toshiba-r)
/dev/sdb1 on /mnt/usb-WD_Elements_10A8_575842314134334139333135-0:0-part1 type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

Comment: It is probably not formatted with an `ext4` file system, but `NTFS` or `FAT` which doesn't support permissions. What is the output of `mount`?

Comment: how to show the output of mount?

Comment: Type the command "mount" in a terminal, press enter, edit your question and paste the output into it.

Comment: Open a terminal and type `mount` and copy and paste it into your question

Comment: i add what appears after the mount command

Answer (score 1):

Your disk is known to the system as `/dev/sdb1` and is mounted read-only (the `ro` between brackets). Moreover, it is NTFS (which the `mount` command reports as `fuseblk`).

Unmount your disk and re-mount it as `read-write`, like this:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
sudo mkdir /mnt/mydisk
sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw /dev/sdb1 /mnt/mydisk
```

This will work unless your external disk has a hardware switch to set it to read-only, which is the case with e.g. many SD-cards.

Comment: Thank you for your proposition but unfortunately, it didn't work

Comment: What is the output of the `mount` command?

Comment: the output of the 'mount' is mentioned in the update 02

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the Type of file system.

Try to format it in ext4 or NTFS. depends on the usage of that HDD.
And make sure that chown and chmod are set properly.

Comment: please, what type of commands that I need to use??? (to avoid mistakes)

Comment: for example. when I click on my external HDD and: 
cd /media/$USER/external_01

and do ll on that HDD I got this:
drwxrwxrwx  1 ralexander ralexander  20K srp  26 01:20 external_01

ralexander is my $USER and my group name.

 if you output says root root then you can read and write only as root.
 you need to change owner and group to that you default user

$ chown -r /path/to/external

and if that work then is ok. If not then check you RWX permissions
$ chmod rwx /path/to/external

i'm kinda in hurry so hope u get point =\

Answer (score 0):

Your drive indeed is most probably formatted with the ntfs file system of MS Windows. That it does mount read only suggests that there are issues with the file system. Ubuntu typically will not automatically mount an ntfs volume with issues.

- Connect the drive to an MS windows system and have it checked with the Windows disk checking tools
- Make sure to disconnect the drive correctly from the Windows system, or turn Windows completely off (no hibernate but a full shut down).

After this, the drive will automatically mount with read and write permissions when you connect it to the USB after you have logged in.

Comment: true what you said its was formatted with the ntfs file system of MS Windows, i tried your proposition but always the same result I am not allowed to write or delete